# Cannot boot to Windows 10 after failed installation of Ubuntu!

Tags: boot, dual-boot, bootloader, windows-10

I was trying to install Linux for a Linux course and now I am stuck. First of all Ubuntu doesn't get installed completely. So every time I restart the computer it asks me if I want to install Ubuntu and enter without installing. I have already install it 4 times but for some reason It is not installing. I am just trying to go back to windows I desperately need my files and program back ASAP. Please Help!!?

Comment: are you install windows and ubuntu in same partition ?

Comment: You only get asked whether to install or try without installing if you don't remove the installation media (DVD or USB drive usually). Remove it and reboot then, it should now boot from the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/

[EDIT]
This link is for Windows 10: http://www.thewindowsclub.com/repair-master-boot-record-mbr-windows

You will need Windows bootable drive like flash drive or DVD. Eventhough its says its for Windows 7 it must also work for others I suppose. However I have not tried it.

1. Boot from windows DVD/Flash drive
2. Select repair computer
3. Choose command prompt
4. Enter the following commands:

   bootrec /fixmbr